# HTML audio not sported in Flutter || Text is working other tags are working But audio is not sporting

Tags: html, json, flutter, response, html5-audio

This data is coming from API in json and value is coming in html tag.
Flutter is not Sported Html audio tag so please suggest me something to archive this.

```
 "message": "<div class='border-bottom pb-1'>Audio Recording</div><table class='table mt-1  border mb-0 table-hover  table-border bg-white table-sm table_format'>\n                                <tbody><tr>\n                                <td class='font-small-1'><audio class=\"player\" src=\"https://sr.rity.com/vr/fetchsound/?callid=7fefab-65f7-41-baa5-49a69e33\" preload=\"metadata\" controls></audio></td>\n
```

I am using this 2 plugins:-

```
  flutter_html_all: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.10.3
```

and here is the flutter code:-

```
child: HtmlWidget( _activityList.message?.toString() ?? ""  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flutter_widget_from_html_core` doesn't support audio, this is mentioned in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html_core):

> These tags requires [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html):
>
> - AUDIO
> - IFRAME
> - SVG
> - VIDEO

You will need to install the other package:

```bash
flutter pub add flutter_widget_from_html
```

...then import it

```dart
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';
```

Optionally, you can tidy up pubspec by removing unused packages:

```bash
flutter pub remove flutter_html_all
flutter pub remove flutter_widget_from_html_core
```